# remove empty option from my dropdown angularjs

Tags: c#, angularjs, dropdown

i am creating a web app and i have a dropdownlist

```
<select id="drdsearch" ng-model="drd" style="margin-top:-39px; margin-left:300px; height:30px; width:200px; font-size:12px;"><option value="select">select</option>
        <option value="default">Default</option>
        <option value="venue">Venue Name</option>
        <option value="date">Date</option>
    </select>
```

with these textboxes

```
 <input type="text" ng-hide="true" ng-show="drd=='default'" placeholder="d" name="default">
    <input type="text" ng-hide="true" ng-show="drd=='venue'" placeholder="e" name="venue name">
    <input type="text" ng-hide="true" ng-show="drd=='date'" placeholder="l" name="Date">
```

i used angularjs for (`hide/show`)textboxes but now when i run my program dropdown automatically included an extra blank option field

now there are four fields in my dropdow
1st (              )`blank`

2nd `default`

3rd`venue`

4th`Date`

what i need to do to remove the extra (`blank option`) from the dropdownlist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialize the value in your `$scope.drd` with `'default'` and you should be fine.

Comment: Sir where i need to initialize the value?

Comment: Either in the controller using the `$scope` variable or you could try `ng-init="drd='default'"`.